# Using Apple Pay JavaScript/NodeJS on Azure

Tags: applepay, applepayjs, azure-ase

I used the following as a working sample to intake JavaScript Apple Pay transactions through a NodeJS server on Azure. There is a whole process you have to go through for the certificates once you have a Developer Account but hopefully it will help out someone.

This runs on Azure Application Service Environment (ASE).

```js
/*
Using Apple Pay JavaScript/NodeJS on Azure  

*/

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require("https");
const http = require("http");
const request = require("request");
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;


console.log("port: "+port);
/**
* IMPORTANT
* Change these paths to your own SSL and Apple Pay certificates,
* with the appropriate merchant identifier and domain
* See the README for more information.
*/
const APPLE_PAY_CERTIFICATE_PATH = "./certificates/apple_pay.pem";
const SSL_CERTIFICATE_PATH = "./certificates/merchant_id.pem";
const SSL_KEY_PATH = "./certificates/merchant_id_local.pem";
const MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER = "merchant.com.yourcompany";
const MERCHANT_DOMAIN = "yourdomain.azurewebsites.net";

console.log("==>> server starting.........");

try {
  fs.accessSync(APPLE_PAY_CERTIFICATE_PATH);
  fs.accessSync(SSL_CERTIFICATE_PATH);
  fs.accessSync(SSL_KEY_PATH);
} catch (e) {
    console.log("==>> error:.."+e);
  throw new Error('You must generate your SSL and Apple Pay certificates before running this example.');
}

  console.log("==>> getting certs:..");
const sslKey = fs.readFileSync(SSL_KEY_PATH);
const sslCert = fs.readFileSync(SSL_CERTIFICATE_PATH);
const applePayCert = fs.readFileSync(APPLE_PAY_CERTIFICATE_PATH);


/**
* Set up our server and static page hosting
*/
console.log("==>> setting up server ");
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public',{ dotfiles: 'allow' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


console.log("==>> setting up post ");

app.post('/postToServer', function (req, res) {
    
    console.log("==>> inside  postToServer");
    console.log(req.body.toCS);
     if (!req.body.url) return res.sendStatus(400);
});

app.post('/getApplePaySession', function (req, res) {
console.log("==>> inside  getApplePaySession post req:");
 // We need a URL from the client to call
 if (!req.body.url) return res.sendStatus(400);

 // We must provide our Apple Pay certificate, merchant ID, domain name, and display name
 const options = {
  url: req.body.url,
  cert: sslKey,
  key: sslKey,
  method: 'post',
  body: {
   merchantIdentifier: MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER,
   domainName: MERCHANT_DOMAIN,
   displayName: 'My Store',
  },
  json: true,
 }

 // Send the request to the Apple Pay server and return the response to the client
 request(options, function(err, response, body) {
     console.log("==>> sending to apple pay server body: ");
    console.log(body);
    console.log(response);
  if (err) {
   console.log('Error generating Apple Pay session!');
   console.log(err, response, body);
   res.status(500).send(body);
  }
  res.send(body);
 });
});

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){
 console.log("error: "+err.stack);
});

app.get('/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association', function(req, res) {
    console.log("==>>1 __dirname"+__dirname);
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association');
  
});

app.get('/.well-known/apple-app-site-association', function(req, res) {
    console.log("==>>2 __dirname"+__dirname);
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/.well-known/apple-app-site-association.file');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(port);
```

Comment: Super useful! Just curious, I noticed in this code the variable sslCert and applePayCert are not used at all. Is that intended?

Answer (score 0):

your those are error:

```
cert: sslKey,
key: sslKey
```

cer: certificate_sandbox.pem

key: certificate_sandbox.key